# Image to byte array in Codename One

Tags: java, image, base64, codenameone

I need to convert an image into a byte array in my Codename One app.

It will be used to create a base64 representation of the image to be used in a BrowserComponent.

I tried this:

```
byte[] bytes=new byte[10];
    String base64IconString="data:image/png;base64,";
    try(InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/icon.png");) {
        bytes=new byte[is.available()];
// the instruction above is wrong. it will fail
// use Util.readInputStream(InputStream) in Codename One instead
// see comments

         Util.readAll(is, bytes);
        base64IconString+=Base64.encode(bytes);
    } catch(IOException err) {
        Log.e(err);
    }
```

I put the result into this:

```
browserComponent.setPage("<HTML><BODY>" + "<img src='"+base64IconString+"' />" + "</BODY></HTML>");
```

It works, but I need to create the base64 string from a Image that has no path or file name because it is from a special class MyImageFromSVGSubset.

This tool is used to generate that class: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/flamingo-svg-transcoder.html

Note: the Image class in CodenameOne has also the int[] getRGB() method.

How to achieve my goal?

Comment: `new byte[is.available()]` ← Eventually that will fail.  From [the method’s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29): “It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream.”

Comment: Yes. There's also `Util.readInputStream(InputStream)` in Codename One that does this correctly and seamlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ImageIO` which is designed exactly for that: converting an `Image` to bytes. However, there's a slightly simpler hack. `EncodedImage` supports this out of the box so:

```
EncodedImage em = EncodedImage.createFromImage(otherImage, jpegOrPNG);
byte[] data = em.getImageData();
```

Also see `BrowserComponent.createDataURI(byte[], mime)`.